# How to mock a function directly (Python)

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

We create mock objects and specify the behavior of methods called on them:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

execute = Mock()
execute.fetchone = Mock(return_value={'state': json.dumps({})})
with patch('modules.data_chat.chatbot.execute', new=lambda x, y, z: execute):
        auto_reply(None, "test_user_id", "Hello?", 1)

assert execute.fetchone.called
assert execute.called
```

code under test (auto_reply) implementation:

```
from tools.db_tools import execute
[...]
cur = execute(conn, sql, (bot_id, channel_id))
state = cur.fetchone()
```

Back in the test code, `execute.fetchone.called == True`. However, `execute.called == False`

Why is `execute.called == False` and how can I fix this? Is `new=lambda x, y, z: execute` correct?

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't call it. You called a lambda, which returned it.

I'm not sure why you are doing this. You should use the mocks.

```
fetchone = Mock(return_value={'state': json.dumps({})})
execute = Mock(return_value=fetchone)
with patch('modules.data_chat.chatbot.execute', new=execute):
    ...
```

Comment: This also corrects the error of treating `fetchone` as an attribute of `execute`, rather than an attribute of the *return value* of `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Roseman put me on the right track. One step in the chain was missing in his answer though. execute should not return fetchone directly, but a cursor mock; which can mock fetchone. I added names to the mocks for debugging purposes:

```
cursorMock = Mock(name="cursorMock")
cursorMock.fetchone = Mock(name="fetchoneMock", return_value={'state': json.dumps({})})

execute = Mock(name="executeMock", return_value=cursorMock)
with patch('modules.data_chat.chatbot.execute', new=execute):
    ...

assert cursorMock.fetchone.called
assert execute.called
```